# Mouse cursor change Javascript - linked DIV

Tags: javascript, hover, cursor

I have this JS code.

I want to show a "hand" cursor when I hover on the div like it would normally do for an a href.

```
$("#button1div").click(function(){
window.location = 'http://google.com';
});
```

How do I make the cursor change to a hand?

Thanks.

Comment: `#button1div { cursor: pointer; }` add this in your css. I think this'll help you.

Comment: I agree. No JavaScript needed.

Answer (score 4):

While you seem to want to do this with Javascript, there is a much easier way to do it with CSS alone:

```
#button1div {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And, I'm not sure if you're really doing anything more than changing `window.location` when that `div` is clicked, but it looks like you could use an `a` element with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#button1div").css('cursor','pointer');
```

will set the cursor as hand symbol.